# Accessing view data inside top level component in Laravel (v8)

Tags: php, laravel, view, components

Is there a practical way of accessing a view's data on a higher level component? Let me explain:

I have a **Base Layout** with just the core HTML tags 
 `views/layouts/base.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
    </body>
</html>
```

A **Main Layout** layout component extending this one 
 `views/layouts/main.blade.php`

```
<x-base-layout>
    <x-header-main />
    {{ $slot }}
    <x-footer-main />
</x-base-layout>
```

Both have component classes for them to work outside the default `views/components` folder.

Then, my **Home View** is set like this 
 `views/home.blade.php`

```
<x-main-layout>
    <h1>{{ $data['my_heading'] }}</h1>
</x-main-layout>
```

from the **HomeController** 
 `app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = { "my_heading" : "My Heading", "my_email" : "my@email.com" };

        return view('home')->with(compact('data'));
    }
}
```

And finally, the real issue. My **Footer Main component** is like this 
 `views/components/footer-main.blade.php`

```
<footer>
    <p>{{ $data['my_email'] }}</p>
</footer>
```

***But, as you might imagine, it doesn't work. I get an error:***

> ErrorException
> Undefined variable: data (View:
> C:\my-project\resources\views\components\footer-main.blade.php)

What would be the correct way of making this work? I know I'm probably missing some Laravel inheritance concept here, but I couldn't get which yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some work I found a solution by using [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers). I'll describe what I ended up with in case it helps someone.

> Note: A component higher in the hierarchy, like the `<x-footer-main />`
> on my example, it's a view, as much as the final one you're calling
> via your route/controller.

Created a **ViewServiceProvider** inside `app\Providers`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\View\Composers\DataComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', DataComposer::class);
    }
}
```

Added the provider to the **config** file. `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    /*
                 * Application Service Providers...
    */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,

],
```

Created the **DataComposer** class and the folder structure like `app/Http/View/Composers/DataComposer.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Data;

class DataComposer
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Dependencies are automatically resolved by the service container...
        $this->data = Data::all();
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}
```

***And it worked!!!***